Estoy intentando resolver un procedimiento almacenado haciendo uso el manejo de transacciones y manejo de excepciones
Problema
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/82kumF2T.png
Elaborar un procedimiento almacenado haciendo uso el manejo de transacciones y manejo de excepciones para poder adicionar músicas en una ventas por medio de un cursor. Debe tener en cuenta lo siguiente.

Debe ingresar el año, mes, número de cédula del cliente y la cantidad de músicas a ingresar.
Se debe iterar todas las ventas por el cliente, año y mes. Si el cliente no existe entonces solo debe filtrar por año y mes.
Se debe registrar las músicas en la tabla VENTADETALLE de forma aleatoria y no debe superar la cantidad de músicas de la variable ingresada.
El campo cantidad de la tabla VENTADETALLE será siempre 1, se debe calcular los totales de la venta al finalizar la iteración del cursor.

Estuve intentando realizar el cursor solamente, pero me quede hasta donde se muestra el código
DECLARE @Anio INT = 2022;
DECLARE @Mes INT = 12;
declare @cantidad int = 2;
declare cur_adiccionar cursor for
SELECT v.IDCLIENTE
FROM VENTA v join CLIENTE cl 
on v.IDCLIENTE=cl.IDCLIENTE
where cl.CEDULA = @CedulaCliente or (YEAR(v.FECHA_REGISTRO) = @Anio and MONTH(v.FECHA_REGISTRO) = @Mes)
order by FECHA_REGISTRO asc
declare @idventa int, @idcliente int,@total real, @subtotal real,@iva real, @dscto real
open cur_adiccionar
fetch next from cur_adiccionar into @idcliente
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    SELECT @IDVENTA = ISNULL(MAX(IDVENTA), 0) + 1 FROM VENTA

    insert into VENTA (IDVENTA,IDCLIENTE,FECHA_REGISTRO,SUBTOTAL,IVA,DSCTO,TOTAL)Values
    (@idventa,@idcliente,getdate(),@iva,@dscto,@total)
    fetch next from cur_adiccionar into @idcliente
end ```


  

